# Importing siunitx into Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to import siunitx Latex package to Python (version 3.7) in order to have cleaner notation when labeling axes.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

pgf_with_latex = {                      # setup matplotlib to use latex for output
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",        # change this if using xetex or lautex
    "text.usetex": True,                # use LaTeX to write all text
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",    # use utf8 fonts 
        r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",        # plots will be generated
        r"\usepackage{siunitx}",
        ]                                   # using this preamble
    }

mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)


x=np.linspace(1,100,10)
y=x
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title(r"Disctances given in [\si{\metre}]")
```

and the error that I receive:

```
runfile('C:/Users/bobra/Desktop/untitled2.py', wdir='C:/Users/bobra/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 304, in _run_checked_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['latex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '--halt-on-error', 'C:\\Users\\bobra\\.matplotlib\\tex.cache\\f37855bf2bbf60cd1cb0626b39b0b8c3.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 341, in __call__
    return printer(obj)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 248, in <lambda>
    png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 132, in print_figure
    fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2065, in print_figure
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 527, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1709, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2607, in draw
    self._update_title_position(renderer)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2556, in _update_title_position
    if title.get_window_extent(renderer).ymin < top:

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 890, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 298, in _get_layout
    clean_line, self._fontproperties, ismath=ismath)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 201, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 448, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 338, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)

  File "C:\Users\bobra\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 317, in _run_checked_subprocess
    exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8'))) from exc

RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'Disctances given in \\\\si{\\\\metre}'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/bobra/.matplotlib/tex.cache/f37855bf2bbf60cd1cb0626b39b0b8c3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-02-25>
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.

) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./f37855bf2bbf60cd1cb0626b39b0b8c3.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 ....000000}{\rmfamily Disctances given in \si
                                                  {\metre}}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on f37855bf2bbf60cd1cb0626b39b0b8c3.log.




<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

When I write regular m instead of `\si{\metre}` in the code, it successfully runs.

Also, when I put some non-siunitx related LaTex input, for example `plt.title(r"Disctances given in $[\AA]$")`, my code also works.

What am I doing wrong when importing siunitx and how can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/userdemo/pgf_preamble_sgskip.html) gave me an idea : I inserted the line

```
mpl.use("pgf")
```

right before

```
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
```

This made the code run without error.

On a side note, the only way to retrieve the plot will be by using `plt.savefig` because `pgf` does not support `plt.show()` :

```
siunitx.py:23: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using pgf, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

[image: siunitx demo]

Comment: Tnak you. One other question: how to change backend to a one that I was using before I entered the line `mpl.use(pgf)`. I tried to just delete that line, but my plots are still not showing. I am using Spyder from Anaconda distribution, if that helps.

Comment: Yes, your plots are not showing because you have no `plt.show()` line. The problem is that `show` is not compatible with `pgf`, so you need to add `plt.savefig("f.png")` or `plt.savefig("f.pdf")` at the end of your program.

Comment: I have been using this solution and for some reason, the titles for my plots do not change. This is also an error present in your example. Any ideas for getting those to change as well?